# Model Matrices for Mixed Effects Models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, matrix

In the `lmer` function within `lme4` in `R` there is a call for constructing a model matrix of random effects, $Z$, as explained [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf), pages 7 - 9.

Calculating $Z$ entails KhatriRao and/or Kronecker products of two matrices, $J_i$ and $X_i$.

The matrix $J_i$ is a mouthful: "Indicator matrix of grouping factor indices", but it seems to be a sparse matrix with dummy coding to select which unit (for example, subjects in repetitive measurements) corresponding to higher hierarchical levels are "on" for any observation. The $X_i$ matrix seems to act as a selector of measurements in the lower hierarchical level, so that the combination of both "selectors" would yield a matrix, $Z_i$ of the form illustrated in the paper via the following example:

```
(f<-gl(3,2))

[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
Levels: 1 2 3

(Ji<-t(as(f,Class="sparseMatrix")))

6 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
     1 2 3
[1,] 1 . .
[2,] 1 . .
[3,] . 1 .
[4,] . 1 .
[5,] . . 1
[6,] . . 1

(Xi<-cbind(1,rep.int(c(-1,1),3L)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   -1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1   -1
[4,]    1    1
[5,]    1   -1
[6,]    1    1
```

Transposing each of these matrices, and performing a Khatri-Rao multiplication:

$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1 &. &. &. &.\\.&.&1&1&.&.\\.&.&.&.&1&1 \end{smallmatrix}\right]\ast \left[\begin{smallmatrix}\,\,\,\,1 & 1 &\,\,\,\,1 &1 &\,\,\,\,1 &1\\-1&1&-1&1&-1&1 \end{smallmatrix}\right]=
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\,\,1 & 1 &.&.&.&.\\\,\,\,\,-1 &1&.&.&.&.\\ .&.&\,\,\,\,\,1 &1&.&.\\.&.&\,\,-1&1&.&.\\.&.&.&.&\,\,\,1&1\\.&.&.&.&-1&1 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$

But $Z_i$ is the transpose of it:

```
(Zi<-t(KhatriRao(t(Ji),t(Xi))))

6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] 1 -1 .  . .  .
[2,] 1  1 .  . .  .
[3,] .  . 1 -1 .  .
[4,] .  . 1  1 .  .
[5,] .  . .  . 1 -1
[6,] .  . .  . 1  1
```

It turns out that the authors make use of the database `sleepstudy` in `lme4`, but don't really elaborate on the design matrices as they apply to this particular study. So I'm trying to understand how the made up code in the paper reproduced above would translate into the more meaningful `sleepstudy` example.

For visual simplicity I have reduced the data set to just three subjects - "309", "330" and "371":

```
require(lme4)
sleepstudy <- sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject %in% c(309, 330, 371), ]
rownames(sleepstudy) <- NULL
```

Each individual would exhibit a very different intercept and slope should a simple OLS regression be considered individually, suggesting the need for a mixed-effect model with the higher hierarchy or unit level corresponding to the subjects:

```
    par(bg = 'peachpuff')
    plot(1,type="n", xlim=c(0, 12), ylim=c(200, 360),
             xlab='Days', ylab='Reaction')
    for (i in sleepstudy$Subject){
            fit<-lm(Reaction ~ Days, sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject==i,])
            lines(predict(fit), col=i, lwd=3)
            text(x=11, y=predict(fit, data.frame(Days=9)), cex=0.6,labels=i)
        }
```

[image]

The mixed-effect regression call is:

```
fm1<-lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

And the matrix extracted from the function yields the following:

```
parsedFormula<-lFormula(formula= Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),data= sleepstudy)
parsedFormula$reTrms

$Ztlist
$Ztlist$`Days | Subject`
6 x 12 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

309 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
309 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
330 . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
330 . . . . . . . . . . 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . . . . . . . . . .
371 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
371 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This seems right, but if it is, what is linear algebra behind it? I understand the rows of `1`'s being the selection of individuals like. For instance, subject `309` is on for the baseline + nine observations, so it gets four `1`'s and so forth. The second part is clearly the actual measurement: `0` for baseline, `1` for the first day of sleep deprivation, etc.

**But what are the actual** $J_i$ **and** $X_i$ **matrices and the corresponding** $Z_i= (J_i^{T}∗X_i^{T})^⊤$ **or** $Z_i= (J_i^{T}\otimes X_i^{T})^⊤$, **whichever is pertinent?**

Here is a possibility,

$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1&1&.  &. &. &. &.& . &. &. &. &. &. &.&. & . &. &. &. &. &. &.\\
.&.&.&.&. & . &. &. &. &. &1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1&1&.& . &. &. &. &. &. &.&.&.\\&. & . &. &. &. &. &. &.&. & . &. &. &. &. &.&.&.&.&.&1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]\ast \left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1&1&1&1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9 \end{smallmatrix}\right]=$

$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 &1&1&1&1&1&1&1&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\0 & 1 & 2 &3&4&5&6&7&8&9&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.&&.&.&.&.&.&1 &1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\ &.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&0 &1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9 \end{smallmatrix}\right] $

The problem is that it is not the transposed as the `lmer` function seems to call for, and still is unclear what the rules are to create $X_i$.

Comment: This is much easier than you are making it out to be. The $Z$ matrix here is simply the (transpose of) the Kronecker product of an identity matrix with the design matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I'll keep working on making sense of all the sub-indeces in the linear algebra skeleton of this function. If it clicks in place, I'll go ahead and answer my own question, but although I know is deep-down simple, the correspondence between the math scaffolding nomenclature and the application to any example is confusing.

Comment: Another good resource for you might be their [lme4pureR](https://github.com/lme4/lme4pureR) implementation, which follows along with the above vignette and is written entirely in R. Maybe `mkZt()` (search for it [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4pureR/blob/master/R/templateApproach.R)) is a good start?

Answer (score 6):

1. Creating the $J_i$ matrix entails producing 3 levels (`309`, `330` and `371`) each one with 10 observations or measurements (`nrow(sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject==309,]) [1] 10`). Following the code in the original link in the OP:

`f <- gl(3,10)`
`Ji<-t(as(f,Class="sparseMatrix"))`

[image]

2. Building the $X_i$ matrix can be aided by using the function `getME` as a reference:

   `library(lme4)
   sleepstudy <- sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject %in% c(309, 330, 371), ]
   rownames(sleepstudy) <- NULL
   fm1<-lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject), sleepstudy)`

`Xi <- getME(fm1,"mmList")`

[image]

Since we will need the transpose, and the object `Xi` is not a matrix, the `t(Xi)` can be built as:

`t_Xi <- rbind(c(rep(1,30)),c(rep(0:9,3)))`

3. $Z_i$ is calculated as $Z_i= (J_i^{T}∗X_i^{T})^⊤$:

`Zi<-t(KhatriRao(t_Ji,t_Xi))`:

[image]

This corresponds to equation (6) in the original [paper](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf):

$$Z_i = (J_i^T*X_i^T)^T=\begin{bmatrix}J_{i1}^T\otimes X_{i1}^T\\J_{i2}^T\otimes X_{i2}^T\\\vdots\\J_{in}^T\otimes X_{in}^T\end{bmatrix}$$

And to see this we can instead play with truncated $J_i^T$ and $X_i^T$ matrices by imagining that instead of 9 measurements and a baseline (0), there is only 1 measurement (and a baseline). The resulting matrices would be:

$J_i^T=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $X_i^T=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1\\0&1&0&1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

And

$J_i^T*X_i^T=\left[
\begin{smallmatrix}
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)&&
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)&&
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)&&
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)&&
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)&&
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\end{smallmatrix}
\right]$

$ \small= \begin{bmatrix}J_{i1}^T\otimes X_{i1}^T && J_{i2}^T \otimes X_{i2}^T && J_{i3}^T\otimes X_{i3}^T && J_{i4}^T\otimes X_{i4}^T && J_{i5}^T\otimes X_{i5}^T && J_{i6}^T\otimes X_{i6}^T\end{bmatrix}$

$=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Which transposed and extended would result in $Z_i=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&0&0&0\\1&2&0&0&0&0\\\vdots\\\\0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&2&0&0\\\vdots\\\\0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&1&2\\\\\vdots\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

4. Extracting the $b$ vector of random effects coefficients can be done with the function:

`b <- getME(fm1,"b")`

```
[1,] -44.1573839
[2,]  -2.4118590
[3,]  32.8633489
[4,]  -0.3998801
[5,]  11.2940350
[6,]   2.8117392
```

If we add these values to the fixed-effects of the call `fm1<-lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject), sleepstudy)` we get the intercepts:

```
205.3016 for 309; 282.3223 for 330; and 260.7530 for 371
```

and the slopes:

```
2.407141 for 309; 4.419120 for 330; and 7.630739 for 371
```

values consistent with:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Reaction ~ Days | Subject, groups = Subject, data = sleepstudy, 
       pch=19, lwd=2, type=c('p','r'))
```

[image]

5. $Zb$ can be calculated as `as.matrix(Zi)%*%b`.